# How to sort a list a string of two list path in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two list that contains the path of files

```
lst_A =['/home/data_A/test_AA_123.jpg',
        '/home/data_A/test_AB_234.jpg',
        '/home/data_A/test_BB_321.jpg',
        '/home/data_A/test_BC_112.jpg',
       ]

lst_B =['/home/data_B/test_AA_222.jpg',
        '/home/data_B/test_CC_444.jpg',
        '/home/data_B/test_AB_555.jpg',
        '/home/data_B/test_BC_777.jpg',
       ]
```

Based on the `lst_A`, I want to sort the list B so that the first and second name of basename of two path in A and B should be same. In this case is `test_xx`. So, the expected short list B is

```
lst_B =['/home/data_B/test_AA_222.jpg',
        '/home/data_B/test_AB_555.jpg',
        '/home/data_B/test_CC_444.jpg',
        '/home/data_B/test_BC_777.jpg',
       ]
```

In additions, I want to indicate which position of two lists have first and second name are same in the basename (such as `test_xx`), so the array indicator should be

```
array_same =[1,1,0,1]
```

How should I do it in python? I have tried the .sort() function but it returns unexpected result. Thanks

Update: This is my solution

```
import os
lst_A =['/home/data_A/test_AA_123.jpg',
        '/home/data_A/test_AB_234.jpg',
        '/home/data_A/test_BB_321.jpg',
        '/home/data_A/test_BC_112.jpg',
       ]

lst_B =['/home/data_B/test_AA_222.jpg',
        '/home/data_B/test_CC_444.jpg',
        '/home/data_B/test_AB_555.jpg',
        '/home/data_B/test_BC_777.jpg']

lst_B_sort=[]
same_array=[]
for ind_a, a_name in enumerate(lst_A):
  for ind_b, b_name in enumerate(lst_B):
    print (os.path.basename(b_name).split('_')[1])
    if os.path.basename(b_name).split('_')[1] in os.path.basename(a_name):
        lst_B_sort.append(b_name)
        same_array.append(1)
print(lst_B_sort)
print(same_array)
```

```
Output: ['/home/data_B/test_AA_222.jpg', '/home/data_B/test_AB_555.jpg', '/home/data_B/test_BC_777.jpg']

[1, 1, 1]
```

Because I did not add the element that has not same name

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: @lvrf It's in the question, the second `lst_B`.

Comment: @lvrf: In the question, I expected two output first is sorted lst_B and array_same

Comment: Loop through `lst_A`, and find the matching element in `lst_B` and append it to the output.

Comment: So, you meant we use loop to find it?

Comment: Yeah. You could use a list comprehension.

Comment: Updated. How to add the element that has different name such as `/home/data_B/test_CC_444.jpg`

Comment: Please don't add solutions to questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will discuss the issue with a SIMPLE technique followed by an APPLIED solution.

**SIMPLE**

We just focus on sorting the names given a key.

**Given**

Simple names and a key list:

```
lst_a = "AA AB BB BC EE".split()
lst_b = "AA DD CC AB BC".split()

key_list = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

**Code**

```
same = sorted(set(lst_a) & set(lst_b))
diff = sorted(set(lst_b) - set(same))

isame, idiff = iter(same), iter(diff)
[next(isame) if x else next(idiff) for x in key_list]
# ['AA', 'AB', 'CC', 'BC', 'DD']
```

`lst_b` gets sorted according to elements shared with `lst_a` first.  Remnants are inserted as desired.

---

**Details**

This problem is mainly reduced to sorting the intersection of names from both lists.  The intersection is a set of common elements called `same`.  The remnants are in a set called `diff`.  We sort `same` and `diff` and here's what they look like:

```
same
# ['AA', 'AB', 'BC']
diff
# ['CC', 'DD']
```

Now we just want to pull a value from either list, in order, according to the key.  We start by iterating the `key_list`.  If `1`, pull from the `isame` iterator.  Otherwise, pull from `idiff`.

Now that we have the basic technique, we can apply it to the more complicated path example.

---

**APPLIED**

Applying this idea to more complicated path-strings:

**Given**

```
import pathlib 


lst_a = "foo/t_AA_a.jpg foo/t_AB_a.jpg foo/t_BB_a.jpg foo/t_BC_a.jpg foo/t_EE_a.jpg".split()
lst_b = "foo/t_AA_b.jpg foo/t_DD_b.jpg foo/t_CC_b.jpg foo/t_AB_b.jpg foo/t_BC_b.jpg".split()

key_list = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```

```
# Helper
def get_name(s_path):
    """Return the shared 'name' from a string path.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> get_name("foo/test_xx_a.jpg")
    'test_xx'

    """
    return pathlib.Path(s_path).stem.rsplit("_", maxsplit=1)[0]
```

**Code**

Map the names to paths:

```
name_path_a = {get_name(p): p for p in lst_a}
name_path_b = {get_name(p): p for p in lst_b}
```

Names are in dict keys, so directly substitute sets with dict keys:

```
same = sorted(name_path_a.keys() & name_path_b.keys())
diff = sorted(name_path_b.keys() - set(same))

isame, idiff = iter(same), iter(diff)
```

Get the paths via names pulled from iterators:

```
[name_path_b[next(isame)] if x else name_path_b[next(idiff)] for x in key_list]
```

Output

```
['foo/t_AA_b.jpg',
 'foo/t_AB_b.jpg',
 'foo/t_CC_b.jpg',
 'foo/t_BC_b.jpg',
 'foo/t_DD_b.jpg']
```

Answer (score 1):

Loop through `lst_A`, get the filename prefix, then append the element from `lst_B` with the same prefix to the result list.

Create a set of all the elements from `lst_B`, and when you add a path to the result, remove it from the set. Then at the end you can go through this set, filling in the blank spaces in the result where there were no matches.

```
lst_A =['/home/data_A/test_AA_123.jpg',
        '/home/data_A/test_AB_234.jpg',
        '/home/data_A/test_BB_321.jpg',
        '/home/data_A/test_BC_112.jpg',
       ]

lst_B =['/home/data_B/test_AA_222.jpg',
        '/home/data_B/test_CC_444.jpg',
        '/home/data_B/test_AB_555.jpg',
        '/home/data_B/test_BC_777.jpg',
       ]

new_lst_B = []
same_array = []
set_B = set(lst_B)
for fn in lst_A:
    prefix = "_".join(os.path.basename(fn).split('_')[:-1])+'_' # This gets test_AA_
    try:
        found_B = next(x for x in lst_B if os.path.basename(x).startswith(prefix))
        new_lst_b.append(found_B)
        same_array.append(1)
        set_B.remove(found_B)
    except StopIteration: # No match found
        new_lst_b.append(None) # Placeholder to fill in
        same_array.append(0)
for missed in set_B:
    index = new_lst_B.index(None)
    new_lst_B[index] = missed
```

[DEMO](http://Standard%20output%20is%20empty)

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'join'

Comment: I always forget that Python's join is backwards from other languages.

Comment: Thanks. It missing the element `'/home/data_B/test_CC_444.jpg'`, And also how to add the 1 to same name position that outputs to `same_array`

Comment: There's no `test_CC` in `lst_A`, how is it supposed to know the order in the result?

Comment: yes. But it has in lst_B. So just add it in any postion in lst_B_out that has different name with lst_A

Comment: Hmm, that's complicated. We need to leave a hole in the result when we don't find a match, and then fill all the holes with the unused items from B.

Comment: Yes. I mean we should maintain all element in lst_B. We just sort the lst_B, not delete elements from it

Comment: You can't sort unless you have a comparison function. If there were 1-1 correspondences between the two arrays, you could get the index of the corresponding elements and compare them. This is just matching up the two arrays, but the mismatches complicate it.

Comment: You can't just take any element when there's no match, you have to take an element that doesn't match some other element.

Comment: So, could you see my example in the question? I think it will be more clear

Comment: Your code has the same problem, it doesn't get `test_CC`

Comment: Yes. That what I want to ask

Comment: Working on it, like I said, it's complicated

Comment: Thanks. I also working on it. I used a flag to check if it is add or not. But it is so complex flag

Comment: Are there always the same number of elements in the two lists?

Comment: Thanks. I got error ValueError: None is not in list

Comment: Yes. They should be same. What is problem if list A number is bigger than list B number

Comment: I fixed some typos, it's working now, as long as the two lists are the same length.

Comment: The problem is if `lst_B` is too long. There will be more unused items than placeholders in the result list.